# What is a “designated civil judge” of a county court?

Tags: england-and-wales, court, judge

See this page that lists them: https://www.judiciary.uk/about-the-judiciary/who-are-the-judiciary/leadership-judges/designated-civil-judges/

But what is the idea of this post?

Comment: What has your own research revealed, e.g. by web search for "What is a “designated civil judge” of a county court?"

Answer (score 1):

[https://www.lawsociety.org.uk/topics/solicitor-judges/apply-for-circuit-judge-vacancies#:~:text=Designated%20civil%20judges%20have%20overall,judges%20and%20fee%2Dpaid%20judiciary](https://www.lawsociety.org.uk/topics/solicitor-judges/apply-for-circuit-judge-vacancies#:%7E:text=Designated%20civil%20judges%20have%20overall,judges%20and%20fee%2Dpaid%20judiciary))

> Designated civil judges have overall responsibility for the civil work
> of the county courts and district registries in a given area,
> including:
>
> providing leadership to the civil judiciary who sit at courts in that
> area (circuit judges, district judges and fee-paid judiciary) ensuring
> efficient judicial business at those courts